# os x alternative to Textmate (no Java or vim or xemacs)

Tags: php, textmate

I am fed up with Textmate. It's great, but it's old and keeps crashing on me. No development in (what, 3+?) years, etc.

So I'm looking for a viable alternative. However, I don't want a bloated and slow editor that  runs on Java (so NetBeans, Komodo, Eclipse, etc are out), nor something that includes the kitchen Sink (goodbye Coda, I already own Espresso but am extremely disappointed that after so long the new version doesn't include variable autocompletion, seriously Macrabbit!). Bbedit is a little too bare-bones for me.

In summary, as the title says, a Textmate replacement that is modern, stable and still in development. Mainly for PHP development. Does such a beast exist?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sublime Text 2?](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)

I guess it's the best alternative for someone who used to use textmate, it has a lot of awesome features, once you get used to it you won't need to use anything else.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to be "that guy", but I've been slowly teaching myself Vim, and… well it works I think. Give it another go if you haven't recently. Make it your mission to be awesome at Vim.

Comment: Thanks, but I hate vi, have hated it since the dawn of time. I'm looking for something that is *modern* and Mac-like. That means no vi, no emacs. Having to remember archaic keyboard shortcuts is not my thing.

Comment: Stop looking at the shortcuts as archaic! I recently worked with a group of pythonistas at a hackathon, and they were all using vim, and got at least twice the work done that I did. So fast!

Answer (score 2):

How about these:

- [Smultron](http://www.peterborgapps.com/smultron/)
- [Kod](http://kodapp.com/)
- [Sublime Text X](http://www.sublimetext.com/x)
- [Chocolat](http://chocolatapp.com/) (still in <strike>alpha</strike> beta, but great)

Comment: Chocolat looks lovely and already supports Lion integration! Nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, TextMate 2 [is in development](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/whats-next/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend BBEdit (http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) - the best I've seen on a mac.  Have been using it for years.  And it even has auto-complete for PHP.

Comment: read the question again. kakubei knows BBedit but doesn't want it: "BBedit is a little too bare-bones for me." (but i would recomment BBedit, too - in my opinion it's simply great)

Comment: I used Bbedit for years until I got fed up with it as well. I found it lacking. Firstly it didn't have variable completion. I think they've since added that, but Textmate had a lot more useful features.

Answer (score 0):

[TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/)!

Unlike BBEdit, which is like $50 (thats just a rediculous price for a text editor),  TextWrangler is free!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/) . It's not free but works great. I've been working with coda for over a year now and I think it's the best development tool.

Comment: Things Coda lacks: variable autocompletion (essential) and code folding (also essential).

Answer (score 0):

Nusphere PhpED is the fastest php IDE I have work with but its not free .

Comment: isn't that Java-based, a branch of Eclipse and those others like Aptana, Komodo, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I've moved to Vim one year ago. The steep learning curve is not a myth but not that hard to climb.

Also I second all Sublime Text 2 mentions. It's what TextMate should have been and probably more.

Comment: Sublime Text 2 looks interesting but at the moment it's missing a lot of functionality that I need like PHP syntax checking and function/classes navigation or listing. I'll definitely keep an eye on it though, it's the only one I've found that looks promising.

Comment: Syntax checking is available via an additional package called vimlinter (I think). Symbol listing/navigation is accessed through Ctrl+R.

Comment: look at the title: no vi, no emacs. I want something modern, pretty, mac-like, functional. I switched to all Mac development 6 months ago and want to bask in all its glory! ;)

Comment: Made a mistake, it's sublimelinter not vimlinter. You said you were missing two features in ST2, now you have those features.

Comment: Oh, I'm liking sublime! Does it have code folding? Can't seem to find it. How about bracket balancing? Also I installed sublimeLinter, but it doesn't seem to work at all. That's one thing I don't like: complexity. I'm hoping it's like this because it's in Alpha. Sure I work with code all day, but I don't want to compile the features of my text editor.

Comment: It's working here: there's a yellowish border around the problematic line as well as a description of the error (`unexpected T_STRING…` for exemple) at the bottom of the window when the line is under the cursor. ST2 is a work in progress and code folding has been present in the latest couple of [dev builds](http://www.sublimetext.com/dev). What do you mean by "bracket balancing"? Is it "jump to matching bracket" (Ctrl+M) or something else? Honestly, ST2 is evolving into something great bu I don't see myself leaving the zen of Vim soon. What did you use before TextMate?

Comment: If none of the existing GUI editors (TM, Coda, Espresso, Vico, Kod, ST2b, MacVim, Aquamacs, BBEdit…) fit your needs you'll definetly need to add the features you need by yourself. Or consider the notion that what you want/need belongs more to IDEs. I would say the most powerful/advanced editors available on the Mac (and elsewhere) are Vim and Emacs. MacVim (my favorite) would be my first choice : it's "Mac-like" and it's Vim. You get its awesome power in a well designed/integrated package. Its shortcuts aren't archaic at all and easy to learn because they are for the most part mnemonics.